# Is there a way to determine if the default signature is used in a mail in Outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook, signature

I am developing an add-in for Outlook 2010. Is there a way to detect if the default signature is used in an email?

I know that there is a bookmark in Outlook called "_MailAutoSig". Is it possible to find this bookmark in the mailbody and read from it? Then I could compare this text with the default signature text.

Thank you for any help or hint in advance!

Comment: To me it is unclear in which context you are trying to get this information. Are you writing an add-in for Outlook? Or are you using a console application that connects to Outlook? Or something completely different?

Comment: I am sorry. I am writing an addin-in for Outlook that detects if an email is sent to an external person. If that is the case the default signature has to be included. That is why I want to know if there is a way to detect this.